# Is is possible to have multiple users in an activity diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, srs

I want to ask that two different users are using the same system and the system depends on both of the users.Will there be a single activity diagram for both the user or will there be two activity diagram each including single user.
If both then how?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You do that simply by adding `ActivityPartition`s like this:

[image]

The partitions are instances of/typed with the actors.

p. 418 of the recent UML 2.5.1 specs:

> **15.7.7 ActivityPartition [Class]**
>
> An ActivityPartition is a kind of ActivityGroup for identifying ActivityNodes that have some characteristic in common.

Comment: But the users are not depending on each other .Then will there be two starting points??

Comment: Isn't this swimlane diagram??

Comment: If so, you have two starting points. This is only an example. Partitions are UML element. You can type them. And the above are typed with the actors. Swimlanes should not be uses. They are only graphics with no real semantics.

Comment: There's no such thing as "swimline" diagram. Swimlines are a way offered in activity diagram to depict responsibilities or other characteristics worth showing. The Swimlines going in the same direction (they might be vertical or horizontal) should depict the same kind of characteristics.

Comment: If the flow is totally apart for those actors then is it really a one flow? If it starts independently and then at some point the interaction/dependency/cooperation occurs then yes, you might want to depict that with two starting point. If the flows starts with one actor and then is passed to another actor then it's exactly as @thomaskilian has drawn.